# Docker percona (mysql mariadb) container stops after running on ubuntu when volume (-v) defined

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, percona, docker-volume

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker 17.05.0-ce I try to setup percona-mysql docker image with host directory mapping (volume). Here is image:

`docker pull percona/percona-server:latest`

And here is container run command:

`docker run --name percona -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -v /home/myuser/db/files:/var/lib/mysql -p 6603:3306 -d percona/percona-server:latest mysql -h docker_host_ip -P 6603`

The problem is that container immediately stop after this command - but when I not use `-v ...` parameter (volume mapping) then container starts without problems. How to solve this problem?

This problem can potentially also be on mysql or mariadb images.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Type following commands on your host:

```
cd /home/myuser/db
sudo chown 1001:0 files
```

Then run container again and thats all :)

## Way

1. After fail of running, I look on logs: `docker logs percona` and see that mysql has no permissions to write to dir `/var/lib/mysql`
2. I run container without volume: `docker run --name percona -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -p 6603:3306 -d percona/percona-server:latest mysql -h docker_host_ip -P 6603`
3. I login to container: `docker exec -it percona /bin/bash`
4. I type: `cd /var/lib`
5. After execute `ls -l` i see near mysql dir following row: `drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql root  4096 Oct  6 14:39 mysql`. This mean that owner is `mysql` and group is `root`.
6. I get mysql user UID by `id -u mysql` (I get **1001**)
7. I check by `groups mysql` that mysql has one group (root). So to get root GID I type `id -g mysql` (I get **0**)
8. The `chown` command allow to set file UID:GID even for users which doesnt exist (!) so we not need to create user `mysql` on host. So after run `chown ...` on host, folder `files` have exact the same user and group that mysql inside container expect.